# How to force all descriptions on the X axis on the chart?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this problem, namely how to force all descriptions on the X axis ?? It's best to set the date not horizontally as it is only vertically ...
Thank you in advance for your help...

[image]

[image]

My code:

```scharp
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    this.chart1.Series["TOTAL"].Points.AddXY(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetDouble(1));

                }



            }
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what framework you're using? Also, some code would be helpful too.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to answer it. The tags `c#` and `.net` narrow it down from "everything in the universe", but there's still "all of the charting libraries that use .NET" to sift through. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: This is a standard Chart control in VisualStudio2012 in WindowsForm.

Comment: Consider editing the tags to include `winforms` and `mschart`.

Comment: Unrelated tip: SqlDataReader is disposable, so should be in a `using` block. `cmd`s declaration isn't shown but (just in case that hasn't been done either) that is also disposable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628.aspx):

> When the Chart control contains a large data set, it may selectively display axis labels. To make sure that all axis labels are visible, set the Axis.Interval property to 1.

Set the [Axis.Interval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval(v=vs.110).aspx) interval to 1:

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```